# getView() is called trice when I only inserted 1 item

Tags: android, adapter

This is my code:

```
path = new ArrayList<String>();
adapter = new PathAdapter(this, path);
path_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And then, in a press of a button i inserted another string:

this is to add and update the list

```
path.add("new string");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and in my adapter:

```
if(view == null){
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pics_row, parent, false);
    holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.ivPath = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.path);

    view.setTag(holder);
    Log.e("view", "null");
}else{
    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    Log.e("view" , "not null");
}
```

The logs is for me to know which condition it went. The problem is that, it called the getView() trice. Why? I only inserted 1 item.

logcat:

```
10-02 18:37:56.332  22783-22783/smartminds.com.ci E/view﹕ null
10-02 18:37:56.335  22783-22783/smartminds.com.ci E/view﹕ not null
10-02 18:37:56.407  22783-22783/smartminds.com.ci E/view﹕ not null
```

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: It supposed to do that, it is redrawing the views every time you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. It means you have 3 items in your list